# Python: Make `input` read and write to custom file descriptors

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input, readline, python-c-api

I want `input(prompt)` to:

- read from `/dev/tty`
- write its prompt to `stderr`

I found this by searching around, but I could not find where `readline_until_enter_or_signal` is defined. It seems to only be defined in the C code, and inaccessible in normal Python. I don't know how to call such a method.

```
def call_readline(stdin, stdout, prompt):
    '''Implementation of PyOS_Readline() in the "readline" module'''
    rl_instream = stdin
    rl_outstream = stdout  # Readline writes to stdout
    return readline_until_enter_or_signal(prompt)
```